# Azure API Management Prevent Subscription Key Visibility for Admins

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is it possible to prevent subscription keys being visible to APIM admins? I want them to only be visible to the developer in question via the developer portal.

I have admin access to an APIM instance. I have access to the subscription keys of all of the user accounts by toggling the `Show/hide keys` option for any particular record. I don't want this to be the case, I would like it to be a secret they generate for themselves that no one else can see.

Is this possible at all? If not is there a similar alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, created the 2 users in Azure and given access to only APIM Resource as `APIM Service Contributor`.

Created the 2 Subscriptions in the APIM by logging to the APIM resource using both of the user's credentials in Azure and given owner access to opposite user.

[image]

Using these subscription keys, we can secure the APIs published to the APIM Resource where we can prevent the users to access our APIs data using those keys, so Admin consent is required to approve the subscription keys request for the users.

I believe, it is not possible to restrict the admins from visibility of Subscription keys in APIM.